# how to fetch date wise data between two dates in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two dates and i want to fetch the data between the dates date wise and if a date has no entry in db so it is comes with the `zero` count, i have mytable in which `id, createddate` columns are there.

I have tried like:

```
select COALESCE(to_char(createddate, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), '0') as date,
       count(id) as totalno  
from mytable 
where  (createddate >= '2017-07-13 00:00:00' 
        and createddate <= '2018-07-13 23:59:59')  
group by to_char(createddate, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 
      date_part('day', createddate)
```

This query does not return me the dates data with `0` totalno which has no entry in db.

[image]

As we can see the dates `15,16,18,22,23` did not come with the `0` count.
please help me out.

Comment: It is better to tell the mistake then down vote to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You might create a tally dates table and then count all the dates. ie:

```
with dates ("date") as
(
select '2017-07-13'::date + i 
from generate_series(0, '2018-07-13'::date - '2017-07-13'::date) v(i)
)
select "date", count(myTable.id)
from dates
left join myTable on dates."date" = myTable.createdDate
group by dates."date";
```

Note: It could be this too:

```
with dates as
(
select "date" 
from generate_series('2017-07-13'::date-1, '2018-07-13'::date,'1 day') v("date")
)
...
```